# Stopping and Play button for Audio (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, media-player

I have this problem, I have some audio I wish to play...

And I have two buttons for it, 'Play' and 'Stop'...

Problem is, after I press the stop button, and then press the Play button, nothing happens. -The stop button stops the song, but I want the Play button to play the song again (from the start) Here is my code:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.megadeth);
```

And then the two public onclicks:

(For playing...)

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
             button.setText("Playing!");
             try {
     mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
             mp.start();
             //
            }
        });
```

And for stopping the track...

```
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         mp.stop();
         mp.reset();

        }
    });
```

Can anyone see the problem with this? If so could you please fix it... (For suggest)

Thanks alot...

James

Comment: *Play button works fine, -first time around
*Stop button works fine, (At stopping audio)
Still the problem of starting audio again =/ -play button :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `prepare()` or `preparAsync()` before `start()`.

See the [API for details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) (look at the state diagram).

Comment: Look what I put...

'mp.prepare' then some ifs... Then 'mp.start' so why isn't it working?

Comment: @James Rattray: Change the line that reads `mp.reset()` to `mp.prepare()` in your button2 code. Reset requires resetting the datasource and calling prepare again - it's to recover from an error.

Comment: So no mp.reset at all? Just mp.stop and then mp.prepare()? -Nope... that doesn't work =/

Comment: Quick fix: mp.pause(); then... mp.Seekto(0); This works, but on i'm guessing this is inefficient?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Android documentation, in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#playraw) page it is said that you could `stop()` a "raw resource" mediaplayer, and then replay it just by calling `reset()` and `prepare()` before calling `start()` again. This doesn't work, as you have noticed.

The problem is that `reset()` clears the audio source and returns to the initial state, so you must set again the data source. Unfortunatelly you can't set a "raw resource" data source, because there is no API for this besides `create()`.

I don't know a clean way of solving this issue. stealthcopter's way works great, but is a pain for your design, as you need the context for each start() call :( And involves destroying and creating a complex object, which has a price for realtime apps like games...

Another way that ensures that context will only be needed for the create() call, is to stop the media player this way:

```
stop()
prepare()
```

but if you call start() now, it won't restart from the beginning. You could call `seekTo(0)`, but the sound will have a bit of noise from the previous play position.

I keep investigating on this. There must be a clean and efficient way of stopping and restarting the mediaplayer when created on a raw resource...

Comment: After reset MediaPlayer returns to "idle" state.
I looked in the page you gave and did not see it.
You can look at this page on the state diagram and see to where reset() get you :)    
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#State%20Diagram

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have working in my program. It releases the media player each time  as I use different sounds each time it is called, however it should work as a work-around for your usage.

Creation:

```
    public MediaPlayer mp=null;
```

Starting:

```
    if (mp!=null){ 
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
    }
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(test.this, soundResource);
            mp.start();
```

Stopping:

```
        mp.stop();
```

Also note that you do not require to use prepare because the create method already calls prepare for you ([API REF](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)).